# MySQL Stored Procedure reuse?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a fairly complex stored procedure `sp_assembly_breakdown` that takes a single parameter `assembly_id`. The output generated is always a single row based on that parameter with about 20 calculated fields (costs and hours).

I also have a query that will create a list of `assembly_id` based on another parameter `panel_id`. I want to somehow call `sp_assembly_breakdown` for each `assembly_id` in that list and combine all results together i.e. one row per `assembly_id` where each row is generated by `sp_assembly_breakdown`.

I want to do all of this at the server end. The idea is that the client application passes a single parameter `panel_id` to a stored procedure which in turn returns the multiple calls of `sp_assembly_breakdown`. The data will be copied to a temporary table in the client and used to generate a report.

Edit: A bit more info...

```
+----------+    +-------------+    
! panel    !    ! assembly    !  
+----------+    +-------------+    
! panel_id !    ! assembly_id !  
! ...      !    ! panel_id    !  
!----------!    ! ...         !  
                +-------------+
```

The `panel` and `assembly` tables have a one to many relationship.
`sp_assembly_breakdown` joins other tables (not shown) related to assembly such as `assembly_part` and `assembly_labour`.

The required output will be of the form (show with example data):

```
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---
! assembly_id ! cost1 ! cost2 ! cost3 ! cost4 ! cost5 ! cost6 ! ...
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---
! 1           ! 100   ! 0     ! 20    ! 300   ! 0     ! 0     ! ...
! 3           ! 200   ! 0     ! 40    ! 100   ! 0     ! 0     ! ...
! 6           ! 300   ! 0     ! 600   ! 200   ! 0     ! 0     ! ...
! 12          ! 400   ! 0     ! 700   ! 300   ! 0     ! 0     ! ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, in case someone might find it useful, here is the essence of the solution that I came up with:

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE sp_panel_breakdown(p_panel_id INT)
BEGIN
    -- create temporary table
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS breakdown;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE breakdown(breakdown_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, assembly_id INT, cost1 DECIMAL(10,2), cost2 DECIMAL(10,2), ..., cost10 DECIMAL(10,2), PRIMARY KEY (breakdown_id));

    -- insert data into temporary table
    SELECT sf_assembly_breakdown(assembly_id) as dummy
        FROM assembly
        WHERE panel_id=p_panel_id;

    -- return temporary table
    SELECT * FROM breakdown;
END

CREATE STORED FUNCTION sf_assembly_breakdown(p_assembly_id INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    -- do cost calculations
    ...

    -- insert calculated costs as a new row in temporary table
    INSERT INTO breakdown SELECT null, p_assembly_id, cost1, cost2, ..., cost10;

    -- return dummy value
    RETURN null;
END
```

Key points:

1) `sp_assembly_breakdown` was converted from a stored procedure to a stored function. This allows it to be called for each row in the SELECT query within the parent procedure `sp_panel_breakdown`.

2) `sp_assembly_breakdown`, rather than returning a single row result set now inserts a single row into a temporary table. This way results can be accumulated for each successive call of the function. Also, the function returns a 'dummy' null value because it has to return something.

3) The parent procedure `sp_panel_breakdown` must create the temporary table `breakdown` to be used in `sf_assembly_breakdown`.

4) The first select query within `sp_panel_breakdown` calls the function `sf_assembly_breakdown` FOR EACH ROW. This returns the 1st 'dummy' resultset.

5) Finally the `sp_panel_breakdown` procedure returns the entire contents of the temporary table `breakdown` as the 2nd recordset.

6) When calling `sp_panel_breakdown`, 2 resultsets are returned. The 1st resultset contains the dummy null values, the 2nd resultset contains the contents of the temporary table `breakdown`.

Answer (score 0):

If `panel_id` is related to `assembly_id` through a table, then you can [define a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html), which I'll call `sp_panel_breakdown`, that encapsulates the table-join, and then select from `sp_panel_breakdown where panel_id = ?` in your application. I *think* that could work. I'm *not* a MySQL guru (far from it).

If you don't already have a mapping of `panel_id` to its component `assembly_id`s in the database, then create a temp-table 'on the fly' for the purposes of the query, and then join on it.  It's a bit ugly, but it'll still be fast; i.e. faster than repeated calls to `sp_assembly_breakdown`, and probably *less* ugly.

Comment: @corlettk Sorry Keith but I think you've missed the point. I've added more info to the original question if it helps. Basically I need to call `sp_assembly_breakdown` multiple times and combine all the rows together.

Comment: Ummm... can't you just select from the stored procedure (as if it where any other function) passing the `assembly.panel_id`? Forgive me, I've only used stored-procedures once, in Ingres, (too many) years ago.

Comment: @corlettk I'm certain you cannot SELECT directly from a stored-procedure in Mysql. I've tried it and it doesn't 'compile'.

Comment: @David, **MySQL Stored Procedure SELECT Example:** http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_stored_procedure_SELECT.php is a lot like how I remember doing this in Ingres.

Comment: @David, Oh poo... of course you need to CALL the stored procedure FOR EACH ROW (not just select from it)! Doh! Are you SURE that a stored procedure is that way to go? Maybe a view would be more suitable, even if the select-column-clauses are uggggly!

Comment: @corlettk a View won't work because they can't except parameters. I think I'm going to do something 'sneaky' involving a temporary table and a stored-function rather than a stored-procedure. A stored function CAN be called FOR EACH ROW within another query. I'll post the solution if I can work it out.